# How do I configure Bolt CMS on an subdomain correctly?

Tags: http-status-code-404, subdomain, bolt-cms

I currently have a working Bolt installation on my main domain (i.e. example.com). But I also wanted a subdomain (i.e. blog.example.com).
I created it, but when I uploaded Bolt to it, but when I tried to access it I only got 404 errors.

I tried copying the Bolt installation from the main domain, then only the main page works, but when I try to access the CMS I get a 404 error. Also if I try to access other pages (i.e. blog.example.com/images) I get a 404.

I tried to change the RewriteBase in the .htaccess to all possible things, but no result.

Also if I do it on another hosting company it is just working, does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is working at another hosting company, maybe that is something non-bolt related issue.
I assume that both of them Apache, so after checking file access rights then I would check apache log.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and found out that mod_rewrite was disabled on my sub domain.